# Hiding a div, if a select is empty

Tags: hide

I have 6 selects wrap in their own div each, and I want to hide the whole div, if the select is blank.

```
<div>
   <select>
     <option></option>
     <option>1</option>
    </select>
 </div>  <--- Hide this div if blank option is chose.
```

Comment: If you hide the div that contains the `select`, how can you select anything?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: I found it actually on another page.... Thank you guys so much for the responses.  Using jquery it has slick way of doing just what I needed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you after something like this? This is hiding a separete div based on your selection. In your question, you are hiding the selection itself if it is blank. If you do that, how can you change your selection, once `select` has disappeared?

```js
var checkTheCat = function(index) {
  if( !index ) hideTheCat();
  else showTheCat();
}

var hideTheCat = function() {
  document.getElementById("toHide").style.display = 'none';
}
var showTheCat = function() {
  document.getElementById("toHide").style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div id="toHide">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg" style="height:100px;">
</div>
Please select below:<br>
<select id="selection" onChange="checkTheCat(this.selectedIndex);">
  <option>Blank option</option>
  <option>The Cat</option>
  <option>Another non-blank option</option>
<select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, found it in another post, thank you so much for the reply.

Comment: That's all right. If it does the job you can accept it - in case someone else stumbles across this question they will know that this answer works.